# Approaches to share sensitive information among android apps

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-securityexception

I've multiple apps on Google Play. I'm looking for the better approaches for them to share some sensitive data (say, some kind of token information) across apps. I've tried content provider approach, but that doesn't fit into requirements. I've heard that using Android KeyChain or keystore, data can be saved in a safe shareable location. But I didn't find much useful sample codes to implement this. Could you share/point to some sample code to be able to save in to keychain/keystore and to retrieve from it?

Comment: Without knowing your "requirements", it will be difficult to explain how anything may or may not meet them. `KeyChain` and `KeyStore` are for keys.

Comment: I'm assuming that I can generate my own keys (say {my_id: "some id"}). This is the sort of structure I'm thinking of storing in a common location that could be accessed among my apps. Is it possible using at all using KeyChain/Keystore approach?

Comment: No, by "key", `KeyChain` and `KeyStore` mean cryptographic keys (e.g., X.509), not "keys" in terms of a `HashMap` or equivalent sort of key-value store.

Comment: oh...I see. Does Android have support to storing app generated "hashmap/string based keys" in some common secure location that could be accessed via my all apps/apks (which are signed with different signing certificates)

Comment: No, other than something you provide yourself via one of your apps (e.g., `ContentProvider`). Android generally tries to avoid central data stores, as they become "dumping grounds", and it is frequently troublesome to be able to try to clear them out when apps get uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

If your apps are signed with the same certificate, you can use signature-level permissions to make them grant each other permissions that aren't available to other apps. Then they can send each other data using intents that are filtered by those permissions.

Comment: Can such applications share data among themselves without even using Content provider?

Answer (score 1):

Your safest bet would be to assign a [sharedUserId](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid) to all of your apps.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="mypackage"
          android:sharedUserId="mySharedUID"
```

Setting a sharedUserId forces Android to assign the same Linux user
for all of your shared apps, thus making it possible for them to read each other's private data.

It even allows them to run on the same process, though I do not see a need for
that in your case.

Once you have this you can share sensitive data using [shared prefs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), internal memory files
or sqlite database. They are all scoped by Linux user, hence will be visible to all shared apps.

If your data is highly sensitive, remember that placing it in internal memory is not
enough. You will also need some sort of encryption: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html

Finally - note that sharedUserId mechanism requires you to sign all shared apps using
the same certificate.